# Javascript code some times don't execute when step into (F11)?

Tags: javascript

The code is as below:
There are breakpoints setting beside the lines (Break Point 1, Break Point 2).

```js
if (!TestSolution)
{
    var TestSolution= {};
}

TestSolution.Utils = TestSolution.Utils || {};

var dummy_ = (function ()
{
    // Sometimes step into the line just pop out. 
    // The following lines will not run. 
    **var self = this;**   // Break point 1. 

    // Subscribe to event optionally unsubscribing first.
    **this.Subscribe = function(source, eventName, handler, unsubscribe)** // Break point 2.
    {
        // By default - always unsubscribe first - there is hardly a reason to have
        // multiple subscriptions for the same combination of controls and events.
        if (!(unsubscribe === false)) $(source).off(eventName, handler);
        $(source).on(eventName, handler);
    }
}).call(TestSolution.Utils);
```

The question is that some times when it goes to break point 1, and when press F11, it doesn't go to break point 2. I feel that "var self = this;" is not running. It just pop out of the function.

Edit: This is debugged in Chrome(Version 41.0.2243.0 (64-bit)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include what browser you're running into this problem on. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: you forgot closing ')' in your self invoking function... `}).call`. Is this only a typo? Check console also for any errors.

Comment: Debugger jumps like that when a function has to be defined and then called. It may create more then one thread for interpreting the code.

Comment: You don't need to remove the event handler. Assigning the same handler to the same event on the same element will **not** create a second identical handler.

Answer (score 0):

This code block is very strange, and it may cause a race problem:

```
if (!TestSolution)
{
    var TestSolution= {};
}
```

I would change it to

```
var TestSolution = TestSolution || {};
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that actually avoids any nascent race conditions; certainly in most languages with active threading, it wouldn't, because `||` or the like is not interlocked.

Comment: Can you tell what is the scope of TestSolution variable if it is not defined before this code?

Comment: `window`, presumably, but I'm not sure that scoping it makes enough of a difference.

Comment: TestSolution variable is defined in a lot of *.js code in the solution. It is all defined in this way.

Comment: When debugged in IE 11, sometimes Calling TestSolution.Utils.Testfunction gives exception about "Unable to get property 'Utils' of undefined or null reference". At this point, "TestSolution" is also undefined. Is it  a "racing" problem?

Comment: Yes, the var TestSolution has only that block scope in which it is defined. After that its memory is marked as free (but not deleted) so it may work for some time until some other program use it.